# AsyncSubject - How to get data only one time?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

Issue concerns using Rxjs in Angular4

RxJS version:
5.5.0

Code to reproduce:
Service

 `subject= new AsyncSubject<String>();
 subject.next(data); 
 subject.complete();`

Component

`ngOnInit(){ 
   subject.subscribe(); 
}`

Expected behavior:
Receive data only one time, and next clean data in subject to not receive it one more time or force unsubsribe subject.

Actual behavior:
In service I have asyncSubject which emit some data. In some component I subscribe my asyncSubject, data comes every component initialization. I tried unsubscribe subject but, after next component initialization it subscribes again.

Additional information:
Angular version 4.4.6
Chrome version 61

**DashboardComponent**:

```
constructor(private userEvents: UserEvents,) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.successLogged();
}


successLogged() {
    this.userEvents.successLoggedObservable.subscribe(message => {
        console.log("WORK");
    });
}
```

**UserEvents**:

```
private  successLoggedObservable = new AsyncSubject<String>();
get successLogged() {
    return this.successLoggedObservable;
}
```

**LoginComponent**:

```
this.userEvents.successLoggedObservable.next("MESSAGE");
this.userEvents.successLogged.complete();
this.stateService.go('dashboard');
```

Comment: So let me get this right, you want to fire an event, then navigate from login to dashboard and receive an event there ? You either have to use `Async` or `Replay` subjects and fix up your use-case or use another form of component communication, such as `router params`. Your logic here makes no sense.

Comment: I would like to pass my login success message to **DashboardComponent**, after I login in my **LoginComponent**. Do you have any idea how can I reach it?

Comment: As I said, if you're navigating to your dashboard component using router you can send data to it with router params.

Comment: I solve it using routing parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is perfectly normal behavior of `AsyncSubject` and `ngOnInit()`. Whenever you subscribe to `AsyncSubject` it emits the last value emitted to it, so every time your component initializes it will receive the last emitted value. If you want to avoid that use regular `Subject` instead (or `PublishSubject`.

Info from official docs: [ReactiveX Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

Comment: Subject does not work. When I go to my component A,where I subscribe Subject Observable and next go to component B, where I call **next** method and back to A everything work fine (subscriber is called). But when I first go to component B and next A, subscriber does not work.

Comment: You can't expect me to help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ReplaySubject(1)` with `publish()` and `connect()` in component,

```
// Service
const source = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1).publish()
source.next(1)
// source.complete() - not needed


// Simulate first subscribing component 
const sub1 = source.subscribe(x => console.log('sub1', x))
source.connect()

// onDestroy
sub1.unsubscribe()


// Now resubscribe
const sub2 = source.subscribe(x => console.log('sub2', x))
source.connect()
// No value emitted
```

Working example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/qVEXaM)

Essentially, `publish()` and `connect()` make the observable hot, so new subscriptions pick up the stream at the point of subscription.

Does not work with AsyncSubject, but I haven't yet figured out why.

Answer (score -1):

that's a common behavior to call ngOnInit in every load. You can create bool variable and if it's already loaded assign false value;

```
subscribed: Boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
  if (!subscribed) {
    subject.subscribe();
    this.subscribed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not work. I every time when component is loaded  **subscribed** have false value and subscriber is invoke.